# Android displaying image from Database

Tags: java, android, imageview

Hi I learned how to grab data from a SQL and display onto TextView. But I'm having little trouble displaying images.

The images are stored in the SQL database as URL but I can't display as an image onto the view.

I've done some research and found on "How to display image with given URL", but I'm just having a little difficulty understanding the concept of grabbing the URL and display .. Please kindly help me. Thank you!

This is the errorLog i'm getting.

Update
Line 159 : photoMe.setImageDrawable(drawable);

```
11-15 14:53:21.450: W/LoadImageFromWebOperations(28444): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: photo
11-15 14:53:21.480: D/AndroidRuntime(28444): Shutting down VM
11-15 14:53:21.480: W/dalvikvm(28444): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c55a68)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.app.android.DirectoryDetailMeActivity$GetDirectoryDetails$1.run(DirectoryDetailMeActivity.java:159)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
11-15 14:53:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(28444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



public class DirectoryDetailMeActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView photoMe;
    TextView txtName;

    String uid;

    String photo = "";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String url_veiw_directory = "directory_detail_me.php";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "photo";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.directory_detail_me);

        uid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        new GetDirectoryDetails().execute();

    }

class GetDirectoryDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        int success;
            try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", uid));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_veiw_directory, "GET", params);

            Log.d("my profile", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
            JSONArray directoryObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DIRECTORY); 
            JSONObject directory = directoryObj.getJSONObject(0);

            txtName.setText(directory.getString(TAG_NAME));

            Drawable drawable = LoadImageURL(TAG_IMG);
            photoMe.setImageDrawable(drawable);                             

            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            photoMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);                         

            }else{

            }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private Drawable LoadImageURL(String url)
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "photo");
                    return d;
                }
                    catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.w("LoadImageURL",e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it, you're passing TAG_IMG to the url loader which means you're trying to run code that looks like `new URL("photo")` and it is failing for obvious reasons (not a proper url).

Comment: @TheZ thank you! I'm trying to figure out how to fix it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand an AsyncTask.  The point is that it does not run on the UI thread, making it possible to do long term IO like HTTP connections.  Wrapping the entire doInBackground in a runOnUIThread is completely counter to that.  Its not your only problem, but its on the list.

The rest is too hard to read due to formatting, but look on line 159.  Some variable you're using there is null.

Comment: yes it's the Drawable LoadImageURL method I think. could you take a look at it and advice me in detail? Thank you kindly.